# Does Kaminari Work with Inherited Resources?

Tags: activerecord, dry, kaminari, inherited-resources

Does anyone know whether the Kaminari gem works with Inherited Resources, because I'm trying to keep my code dry and don't want to repeat myself?

What the plan is, is to render 3 different tables i.e. an Errors table, Messages table and Subscribers table using one partial. However because I'm using Inherited Resources I need all of the code that I'd use in the errors controller, messages controller and subscribers controller, to come through the Admin Application Controller.

I hope this makes sense to anyone reading this

Here's my code:

**Admin Application Controller**

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < InheritedResources::Base
protect_from_forgery
include ResourcesHelper
layout "admin"

#Setup
before_filter :set_resource_variable
before_filter :set_pagination_variable, only: :index

#Authentication
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :authenticate_admin!

#Authorization
skip_before_filter :check_authentication

#Index
#Custom Index For Application/Index (no inheritance) 
def index
    @users = User.all
    @attributes = %w(messages subscribers)
end

#Create
def create
    create! { collection_path }
end

#Update
def update
    update! { collection_path }
end


private
#Set Model Variable
def set_resource_variable
    @resource = self.resource_class
    @model = "#{@resource}".downcase.to_sym
end 

#Strong Params
def permitted_params
    attributes = attributes(@resource) + %w(user_id admin_id) + [image_pages_attributes: [:caption, image_attributes: [:image]]]
    params.permit(@model => attributes)
end
end
```

**Errors Controller**

```
def collection
    @errors ||= end_of_association_chain.page params[:page]
end
```

**Table Partial**

```
<h2><%= model %></h2>
<% unless collection.blank? %>
<table class="sort">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <% model.attribute_names.each do |attr| %>
                <th><%= model.human_attribute_name(attr) %></th>
            <% end %>
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
            <% if model.name == "Error" %><th>&nbsp;</th><% end %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%= render partial: "admin/resources/table/row", collection: collection, as: :resource, locals: {model: model}  %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the stack trace.
This error was thrown due to a current_page error:

```
undefined method `current_page' for nil:NilClass
```

**Stack Trace**

```
kaminari (0.15.0) lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb:18:in `paginate'
app/views/admin/resources/_table.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_admin_resources__table_html_erb___69500511_4075212'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
app/views/admin/application/index.html.erb:14:in `block in  _app_views_admin_application_index_html_erb__1045387382_50813388'
app/views/admin/application/index.html.erb:12:in `each'
app/views/admin/application/index.html.erb:12:in  `_app_views_admin_application_index_html_erb__1045387382_50813388'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in  `_run__894777034__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in  process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
lib/error_alert.rb:14:in `call'
rack-cors (0.2.9) lib/rack/cors.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2)      lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__692376707__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Hmm i'd say and I'm just guessing, this isn't perhaps and issue with Kaminari but somewhere your database result is perhaps coming back as nil and Kaminari is trying to call current page on it cause the error. can you provide the stack trace as well? I have the answer I gave working perfectly in an application I've built.

Comment: Are you calling the paginate method anywhere? <%= paginate @errors %> can you also check that the collection being returned by your controller isn't nil? and perhaps trying createing a simple controller using inherited resources to make sure that its correctly working?

Comment: Yes I am calling it in Table partial (I realize it doesn't show it in the code i posted)

Comment: I cant seem to see anything wrong with what you have perhaps someone with a bit more knowledge might be able to comment.

Comment: I think I'm just going to keep working at it. Thanks for you help though, much appreciated!

Comment: "because I'm trying to keep my code _dry and don't want to repeat myself_" -- You already failed :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it does judging from this snippet from https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  protected
    def collection
      @projects ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
end
```

So for Kaminari you might do this:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  protected
    def collection
      @projects ||= end_of_association_chain.page params[:page]
   end
end
```

<strike>Although I haven't had a chance to try it yet.</strike>

I have tested this and it works perfectly.

Comment: It hasn't worked so far. I got an undefined method `current_page' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry joe is it possible you can post the whole thing include the view and the entire controller?

Comment: Yeah sure, I pressed enter by accident

Comment: I'm trying to paste my code in but it keeps telling me that only one @user can be notified

Comment: Would it be best to open up a chat?

Comment: Hmm I've just updated my answer, which I've had a chance to test works fine for me.

Best not to use chat better to share with the community.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45807/discussion-between-joe-hilton-and-rtype)